# Silverlight binding problem to nested ViewModel class

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding

A TextBlock has the following binding :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sum, FallbackValue=9999}"></TextBlock>
```

DataContext is set in SL app constructor

```
ViewModelClass viewModelObject=new ViewModelClass();  
public Calculator()
        { ....
DataContext=viewModelObject;
}
```

Right now im in investigator mode so I removed all DataContext occurences from text so this one is the only one in whole project currently.

my ViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and property Sum exists.

If I change `public int Sum` to `public int SumDOESNTEXIST` and launch SL application I get an error that property Sum is not found, so binding is working to some extent.

`NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");` is fired where needed

However as I found out in my base code for VM following `if` results to false , so noone is subscribed to Event.

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

As a result Sum property is updated , but TextBlock doesn't indicate that.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I am using OneWay binding (but TwoWay doesn't change anything fyi) cause I need to update the textBlock property only when the source property changes.(definition of oneway binding)

As for DataContext, I added a fairly direct check here:

```
internal void sum_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(mySadLabel.DataContext== viewModelObject)
      MessageBox.Show("correct");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");
 }
```

MessageBox is shown..

If DataContext is set to INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation I belive there **should** be subscribers to PropertyChanged event? in my case they are absent however.

Comment: You're correct, you have the correct mode.

Comment: inspiring, but not working! event is null, and noone is interested in updates it could fire..

Comment: Are you using a specific mvvm framework?

Comment: everything is default, just my code on top of it, NotifyPropertyChanged method is very simple INotifyPropertyChanged implementation which worked on other controls

Comment: Maybe show the code where you set the data context.

Comment: I would recommend posting complete, actual code.  Might be that you have a typo that someone can spot.

Comment: added update about data context. As for complete code sadly I believe that I covered everything that is connected to this label above. I've been rechecking and testing for 2.5 hours already and am kinda lost. Why can there be no subscribers to event?

Comment: That code is setting the data context for a label?

Comment: The BindingPath says "Sum" and you are notifying on "ChipsSum".  Post complete code (unless that's the source of the problem).

Comment: yeah sorry for that. thats the only thing I edited out of the actual code (except label name), wish it was the cause!!

Comment: I'd recommend mvvm lights ViewModelLocator.  It's simple to setup and let's you set bindings at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures out problem was in ViewModel definition.

After I added manual control over PropertyChanged event

```
private PropertyChangedEventHandler m_PropertyChangedHand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GetType() + "subscribed");
            m_PropertyChangedHand = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(m_PropertyChangedHand, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GetType() + "UNSUBSCRIBED");
            m_PropertyChangedHand = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(m_PropertyChangedHand, value);
        }
    }
```

I was able to see 2 messageboxes popup one after another right after DataContext is set

MyApp.TestVmNest+TestClassVMsubscribed
MyApp.TestVmNest+TestClassVMUNSUBSCRIBED

I was able to reproduce such behaviour with following class replacement structure

```
public class TestVmNest
    {
        internal class TestClassVM : Observable
        {
            public int Sum
            {
                get { return 1337; }
            }
        }
    }
```

My original viewModel class however is internal & internal nested too but for simple class like that I get NO MSG BOXES AT ALL when application is launched so not sure why that could be the case

```
    internal class TestVmNest
    {
        internal class TestClassVM : Observable
        {
            public int Sum
            {
                get { return 1337; }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why this public-internal nested class gets added as PropertyChanged, checked that it has `Sum` field by binding engine, but is quickly removed afterwards and never actually binds.

So it has to be public public in order to work correctly it appears..

Answer (score 0):

Again, I suggest you post ALL your code.  Something is weird, as you seem to be setting the datacontext of your named label, which doesn't exist in what you posted.

In any case, I think you are confusing dataContext with binding path (seems like you might be using both).  Your *view's* dataContext should be set to your INotifyPropertyChanged object (usually a viewModel), and your textblock should bind to one the notifying properties (Sum or ChipsSum in this case).

Comment: Ya post as much of the view and vm, and full code behind.  If any.

Comment: as you can see I am not setting for label, I am using a strict check using ==, that setting it to the parent control (my entire app) did indeed set it to its children (my label) I thought maybe there was a way label didnt inherit it at some point, but its set correctly. As for code.. I have no idea what to add guys! this whole chain of responsibility for binding is in initial post. I know it should be working and various checks show that everything is set correctly, what could be the cause that VM has no subscribers, but is used as DataContext? nothing known ?

Comment: I see what you do in the ctor but what is viewModelObject?  Type, scope, can't tell.

Comment: Ive added code about setting DataContext in the beginning of post, why do you think its incorrectly set? I am setting DataContext in 1 place , and its equal to my object for every child control of application

Comment: I'm pretty sure posting complete code would get you an answer, but if you're unwilling, you're unwilling.

Comment: So Calculator.xaml is the view and Calculator.xaml.cs is the codebehind?  If you want to send the code I'd look at it derek.beattie at gmail.com, I'm curious now :)

Comment: hey derek, heres the result of my further investigation, its fairly weird behaviour I think